# Is there a way to enforce ID ordering in Liquibase?

Tags: liquibase

My intent is to strictly enforce the ID ordering of changesets, so if someone knows how to do that you can skip the detailed explanation.

I'm setting up a Liquibase system. I prefer Flyway, but Liquibase offers more for free and my company isn't paying for Flyway. We will use Liquibase to execute scripts against our QA environment, and every 2 weeks when we do a prod release we will then execute those scripts against prod.

So in QA, let's say I have the following changesets already executed (these are the IDs):

20230501
20230502
20230503

Then I add a new changeset with the ID of 20230401. This would be accepted by liquibase, and the changelog in QA would look like this:

20230501
20230502
20230503
20230401

However, when I then to go execute these changesets against production, they would actually be executed in this order:

20230401
20230501
20230502
20230503

As you can see, the most recent changeset is actually executed first in this scenario.

The problem is that IDs are not strictly validated as part of the migration. Despite having an ID that is ahead of the existing IDs, Liquibase will still execute it and put it at the end of the list. Then, when this batch of changesets are executed in prod, the execution order will be different.

My intent is to identify some setting within Liquibase that will allow me to strictly enforce changeset ordering by ID, the same way Flyway does.